# Can you prep a spell outside your main phase in Aeon's End?

Tags: aeons-end

The Aeon's End rules say, that if you focus one of your breaches, you may prep a spell onto that breach. Are you also allowed to do that outside of your own main phase?

For example an ally might focus one of your breaches. Can you immediatly prep a spell onto that breach?
Or if you cast Jagged Lightning in your casting phase and choose to focus one of your breaches, does this allow you to prep one of your spells and even cast it in the same casting phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusing a breach and prepping a spell to a breach are separate actions.

Rules p. 3:

> "The only time that spells can be prepped to a closed breach is during the player's turn in which that breach was focused."

So when an ally focuses your breach, that doesn't help your prepping, because the focus didn't happen on your turn. (But it does make future opening cheaper. And it did happen on *their* turn, so if they had the ability to prep a spell to your breach that could work.)

When a spell you cast focuses your breach, that did happen on your turn, so you can prep a spell to it that turn (in the main phase) without focusing it again.

Comment: That is not true, there are other abilities that allow you to focus and prep a spell out of turn. It was the ability of a single character in the game though unfortunately I no longer have access to a copy of the game to provide the text.